# Java Garbage Collection with Assignment of Variables

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have been going through the Java tutorials on the Java website and have been left confused with an answer they gave to a question.

The question is as follows: "The following code creates one array and one string object. How many references to those objects exist after the code executes? Is either object eligible for garbage collection?"

```
String[] students = new String[10];
String studentName = "Peter Smith";
students[0] = studentName;
studentName = null;
```

Answer: "There is one reference to the students array and that array has one reference to the string Peter Smith. Neither object is eligible for garbage collection."

Why is `studentName` not eligible for garbage collection? Nothing is pointing to `studentName`, and it's value is `null`.

Comment: Objects are garbage collected, not variables.

Answer (score 4):

studentName is a *variable* not an *object* - you garbage collect only objects. 

The only objects in here, as mentioned are the created `String[]` and "Peter Smith", and both are reachable, and thus not eligable for GC.

Answer (score 0):

`studentName` is reference to `Object` not an actual `Object`,

If you mean Object referred by `studentName`

```
String studentName = "Peter Smith";
```

then it is still being referred by `students[0]`

```
students[0] = studentName;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you look at the documentation on that site it says the following in the [summary page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/summaryclasses.html):

"The garbage collector automatically cleans up unused objects. An object is unused if the program holds no more references to it. You can explicitly drop a reference by setting the variable holding the reference to null."

Even though the reference to "Peter Smith" is released by *studentName* when it is set to null, the string array *students* still has a reference to that object so it's not eligible for garbage collection.  The array itself also still has a reference to it. If you put this in a small program and run it and print out students[0] after this code block it will print "Peter Smith"